# Send Notification from Alexa to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit, magic-mirror

I have a Magic Mirror running on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I want to control some modules with my Alexa Echo.
So basically all I need is to say something that Alexa can auto-detect and then send it to my Raspberry Pi.

I already found the Automation Speech Recognition Skill Kit by Amazon which is probably the service I would need for this but I'm not sure if you can send a Push-Notification to the Raspberry Pi.

Does anybody have experience with ASR? Any suggestions how to implement this kind of skill?